# I need to override the SitecoreFieldLinkMapper, how do I ensure that the mapper isn't ran twice?

Tags: glass-mapper, links

When overriding SitecoreFieldLinkMapper, I add my new custom mapper to the CreateResolver method so it can be ran with all the other custom mappers. How do I ensure that only this custom mapper is ran and not the standard glass link field mapper? I think both might be executing.

Answer (score 3):

You can replace the standard link resolve in the Glass Dependency resolver. This is done in the  CreateResolver method:

```
 public static IDependencyResolver CreateResolver(){
        var config = new Glass.Mapper.Sc.Config();
        var dependencyResolver = new DependencyResolver(config);
        // add any changes to the standard resolver here


        dependencyResolver.DataMapperFactory.Replace<SitecoreFieldLinkMapper, MyLinkResolver>(()=> new MyLinkResolver());



        return dependencyResolver;
    }
```